# How to populate a nested array of refs in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following documents on a "mealPlans" MongoDB collection:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4e1c7471b52b63b1ff3c25"),
    "name" : "My Meal Plan",
    "meals" : [ 
        {
            "name" : "Breakfast",
            "foods" : [ 
                {
                    "servingSize" : 100,
                    "food" : ObjectId("5f4a5b3486b27b159befb995")
                }, 
                {
                    "servingSize" : 50,
                    "food" : ObjectId("5f4a5b3486b27b159befb996")
                }
            ]
        }, 
        {
            "name" : "Lunch",
            "foods" : [ 
                {
                    "servingSize" : 100,
                    "food" : ObjectId("5f4a5b3486b27b159befb995")
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

And another collection "foods" with the nutritional information of each food, eg:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5f4a5b3486b27b159befb995"),
    "name" : "Fenway franks",
    "carbohydrate" : 4,
    "calories" : 280,
    "measurementUnit" : "g",
    "fat" : 26,
    "protein" : 12,
    "servingSize" : 100
}
```

How could I replace the food reference in the meal plan document with the nutritional information of each food? I have tried the following to get all the needed information but I'm just not having success to group everything back:

```
db.getCollection('mealPlans').aggregate([
 { "$unwind": "$meals" },
 { "$unwind": "$meals.foods" },
 { "$lookup": {
        "from": "foods",
        "localField": "meals.foods.food",
        "foreignField": "_id",
        "as": "meals.foods.food"
 }}
])
```

I have been struggling for several hours trying different methods all with different results but no one with the proper results. Any advice will be welcome.

Thanks

Comment: You are getting some output. You can try using the Aggregation Operators `arrayToObject` _and / or_ `objectToArray`, along with the `$group` stage to re-build the document. What is the output you are expecting?

Comment: I was getting the desired output (all the food information instead of the ObjectId) but each one on a separate document. All I needed was to put everything together and @turivishal answer does exactly that. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add this after your all pipelines to reconstruct your `foods` and `meals` array,

- `$unwind` to deconstruct food array
- `$group` to reconstruct `foods` array
- `$group` to reconstruct `meals` array

```
  {
    $unwind: {
      path: "$meals.foods.food",
      preserveNullAndEmptyArrays: true
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: {
        _id: "$_id",
        name: "$meals.name"
      },
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      foods: { $push: "$meals.foods" }
    }
  },
  {
    $group: {
      _id: "$_id._id",
      name: { $first: "$name" },
      meals: {
        $push: {
          name: "$_id.name",
          foods: "$foods"
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

[Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Mp0V6_T4UIr)